# Style sibling of parent on hover of child

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="content-1"> A </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-2"> B </div>
</div>
```

On hover of content-1, I want to style content-2

Comment: then will you accept to use `js` (no other way)

Comment: *"On hover of content-1, I want to style content-2"* **or** *"On hover of content-1, I want to style parent"*?

Comment: "On hover of content-1, I want to style content-2", I can do it with js but I want to see if there is a solution with plain css @Neptotech-vishnu

Comment: no way, `css 4`(a new feature of `:has`) could do it,so wish for release of *css 4*

Comment: Hello @kavandalal, if the <div class="content-2"> B </div> is child of parent I can do it, is it outside right?

Comment: @AwatITWork it is outside of 'parent'

Comment: If they don't share the same parent you can't do it

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found a solution for this, which I never used which is a **">"** sign.
I used **Main** for doing this, I used **content-1** but it doesn't work for me, simce to me it act like then first-child and last-child or something like that.
here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stack13</title>

    <style>
        
        .main:hover > .content-2{
            background-color: red !important;
            color: blue !important;
        }


    </style>



</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="content-1"> A </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-2"> B </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

```css
.main{
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.content-1{
  border: 1px blue solid;
}

.main:hover > .content-2{
    background-color: red !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stack13</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="content-1"> A </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-2"> B </div>    
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure to explain that this will style .content-2 on hover of .main and all of its children rather than just .content-1

Comment: Yes, but it is clear I think

Comment: Also you can turn your code into a snippet with Ctrl+M or the snippet button in the editing toolbar so that people can run it with one click

Comment: Actually, I have targeted content-2, so only that will be affected. try it, I have edited the answer including Snippet.

Comment: `On hover of content-1, I want to style content-2` Read it carefully :)

Comment: So, can you read my answer too carefully :), USED Main,
I started with your answer but for me not working for Firefox and Chrome. so

Comment: I'm not sure why my code isn't working for you. Please listen to the advice I am giving you, you have not answered the question accurately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243089/discussion-between-awatitwork-and-zach-jensz).